SSL validation failed for <url>[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1006)
trying to connect aws share services landing zone. I installed cli from given command in aws cli documentation for windows. using gitbash to connect this. what is this error and what is this url given? any kind of additional access I want for this?
SSL validation failed for https://oidc.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/client/register [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1006)
what is this error?
url:-https://oidc.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/client/register -- what is this for
I tried to commands to fix this:-
pip install certifi
pip install flask
and updated the cert by using :-python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
But still not working.
